# How to load and cache translations?

Tags: symfony

I'm using  gettext translations for SF2 and I arrange my translation files in different folder structure than the normal bundle (I kind of created my own mini plugin system for some specific needs).

In any case, this is how I'm loading my translation files:

```
$finder = new Finder();
$finder->files()->filter(function (\SplFileInfo $file)
{
    return 2 === substr_count($file->getBasename(), '.') && preg_match('/\.\w+$/', $file->getBasename());
})->in($dirs);
foreach ($finder as $file) {
    // filename is domain.locale.format
    list($domain, $locale, $format) = explode('.', $file->getBasename(), 3);

    // we have to add resource right away or it will be too late
    $translator->addResource($format, (string)$file, $locale, $domain);
}
```

It works well, the only problem is that it is not cached which is not very efficient. I wonder what I should do instead to cache these translation?

Comment: Translations are cached by default, not sure why you would create your own system. Anyway, a cached translation is just a file in the app/cache dir, you can store your results there.

Comment: The reason is that I'm not using Bundles, I kind of created my own system of plugins so I basically will need to write my own code to loop through each plugin to scan and get the translation files (the code above), and so far it seems like if I use that code it does work but it will not cache my translations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I forgot the declare translator in the config file and thus the translation pass doesn't work

```
framework:
  translator: { fallback: %locale% }
```